# Strange namespace issue on php

Tags: php, namespaces

I have found [this article](https://laravel-news.com/automatic-facades) where I can found this syntax on php:

```
use Facades\ {
    App\Zonda
};
```

I can't figure out how it works, Facades should be a namespace but I can't understand how it is related to the rest. I tried to check out documentation but I didn't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's new PHP7.* `use` syntax. You can find more in official [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.group-use-declarations).

> Group use declarations
>
> Classes, functions and constants being imported from the same
>   namespace can now be grouped together in a single use statement.

Answer (score 0):

In your case :

```
use Facades\ {
   App\Zonda
};
```

Equals :

```
use Facades\App\Zonda;
```

The group use declarations has been introduced in PHP 7 and are usefull when you need to include multiple classes defined in the same namespace.

The documentation can be found in here : http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.group-use-declarations